# Xamarin Test Recorder is not run on real device

Tags: xamarin.android

I followed the steps below:

1. Connect Device to PC (USB Debugging is ON)
2. Go to Test class on VS 2015 enterprise
3. Click on Record New Test button
4. Choose APK file

Observed: Nothing happen

Comment: Repair visual studio or try clearing vs cache that might do the job.

Comment: @G.hakim: Thanks for your reply. But I installed VS 2015 Enterprise , cleaned project and cleared cache, but It still not work.

Comment: When did you install your vs?

Comment: @G.hakim: on yesterday

Comment: I'm try repairing VS now. It's in progress

Comment: Problem is still there after repair VS @G.hakim

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xe8wwxh4pmqd9ja/Untitled.png?dl=0